# Can you create a browser app with PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps

I am brand new to PowerApps and am evaluating it. In some reading I've done, it seemed to be possible to create browser and mobile apps with PowerApps. However, when I went into the PowerApps studio and created a new app, the only two choices I had was to use a phone template or tablet template. So it appears you can only create apps that run on a device and not within a browser as a true browser app. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can now create canvas apps of almost any size by customising the screen dimensions, so that you can produce proper browser apps.

Just go to App settings -> Screen size + orientation -> Select 'custom' and then input the desired width and height in pixels.

Width can be in the range 50-3840 and height 50-2160

[image]

Comment: Does PowerApps build a responsive browser UI? So, if I specify a large size, will it render properly on a smaller display, like a responsive UI should?

Comment: PowerApps does not currently build a responsive UI in the traditional understanding of the term, as far as I know.  However, a large screen size will render properly on any device, everything will just be scaled down.  It is not responsive in that PowerApps does not know that images are to cropped but text to be scaled etc., and there is no way to programme that.

Answer (score 0):

Both the phone and the tablet template for Canvas apps will run both in a browser and on your phone. Further, you can change the aspect ratios if you like.

Comment: That’s good to know but I suspect running an app designed for a tablet wouldn’t look very good in a browser on a medium to large sized monitor.